# Criando um gráfico de barras para comparar dados

Tags: python, pandas

Estou fazendo o curso de data science da udacity. É meu primeiro contato com a programação, então não julguem os erros bobos haha.

Estou comparando dois data frames com informação de carros do ano de 2008 e 2018. Uma das questões pede para comparar a melhoria no consumo de combustível por classe de veículo.

Tirei as médias de consumo de cada classe usando o grupby, depois joguei essas médias numa variável e tentei criar um gráfico para comparar a evolução de um ano para o outro. Minha tentativa foi essa:

```
ind = np.arange(3, 7)
width = 0.2
labels = ['SUV', 'LC', 'MC', 'Minivan', 'Pickup', 'SC', 'SW']

bar_08 = plt.bar(ind, [18.47, 18.50, 21.60, 19.11, 16.27, 21.09, 22.36], width, color='r', label=2008)
bar_18 = plt.bar(ind+width, [17.19, 22.67, 26.90, 20.80, 18.08, 24.37, 27.52], width, color='b', label=2018)

location = ind+width/2
labels=labels
plt.xticks(locatio, labels)
plt.legend()
```

O erro que aparece é o seguinte:
shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape

Alguém pode me iluminar nessa questão?

Answer (score 2):

Seguindo este código disponibilizado pelo site do matplotlib : [Matplot Barplot Tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html)

Podemos perceber que ele define o índice como um valor fixo, no caso o 5(variavel `N`) e depois passa este valor para o `ind=np.arange(N)` e cria o range. Está e a quantidade de dados a serem plotados como vemos por exemplo em `men_means = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27)`, são 5 valores.

No seu caso, você definiu um range de 3 á 6, com o `np.arange(3,7)` e esta tentando plotar 7, `[18.47, 18.50, 21.60, 19.11, 16.27, 21.09, 22.36]` por isto recebe o erro de shape, vamos dizer que o matplot não estava preparado para receber 7 valores, pois só foram definidos 4(o np.arange(3,7) nos retorna [3, 4, 5, 6]).

Se você alterar o valor 7 para 10 no `arange` conseguiria plotar. Porém o código fica menos legível.

Tu poderia assim como no tutorial acima, definir o numero de dados que você ira plotar em uma variável, e passar ao `arange`, por exemplo:

```
N = 7
ind = np.arange(N)
width = 0.2
labels = ['SUV', 'LC', 'MC', 'Minivan', 'Pickup', 'SC', 'SW']
```

Porem sempre que você adicionar um dado ou um label no eixo X, teria de alterar este valor, então para seguir por exemplo o numero de labels, tu pode usar o tamanho dela para definir a quantidade de dados plotados.

```
ind = np.arange(len(labels))
width = 0.2
labels = ['SUV', 'LC', 'MC', 'Minivan', 'Pickup', 'SC', 'SW']
```

Em ambos você terá o seguinte retorno de forma gráfica.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso você queira adicionar mais colunas por exemplo, utilize a segunda forma, e só terá de adicionar novos valores na lista `labels` e nos dados a serem plotados.

```
ind = np.arange(len(labels))
width = 0.2
labels = ['SUV', 'LC', 'MC', 'Minivan', 'Pickup', 'SC', 'SW', 'TESTE']


bar_08 = plt.bar(ind, [18.47, 18.50, 21.60, 19.11, 16.27, 21.09, 22.36,5], width, color='r', label=2008)
bar_18 = plt.bar(ind+width, [17.19, 22.67, 26.90, 20.80, 18.08, 24.37, 27.52,5], width, color='b', label=2018)

location = ind+width/2
labels=labels
plt.xticks(location, labels)
plt.legend()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]